# Including template code in multiple compilation units, will it always link without inline?

Tags: c++, templates, linker

Suppose I have template code in `MyHeader.h`, which is then included in 2 compilation units, `A.cpp` and `B.cpp`. Both of these files then instantiate the same template function, say `f<int>();` (the latter defined non-inline in `MyHeader.h`).

As far as I know, what's happening is the following. The compiler generates the code for `f<int>();` in both `A.obj` and `B.obj`, then the liker discards one of the symbols at the linking stage.

**My question:** is this approach always "safe"? I.e., can there be linkers that will complain about duplicate symbols? **Does the standard say anything about this?** If yes, I cannot see any solution then to make all my template functions `inline`.

Comment: Yes, template code is implicitly `inline`.

Comment: @DanielFrey I'm reading the [*C++ templates*](http://www.amazon.com/C-Templates-The-Complete-Guide/dp/0201734842) book by Vandervoorde and Josuttis, and they say it's not true (Sec. 6.4), template functions are not implicitly inline: *"This may lead to the impression that template functions are inline by default. However, they are not"*. Do you happen to have any standard reference to support the claim?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath that I kind of guessed, but I'd like to see some formal specification as to why is 100% safe.

Comment: I would think 3.2.6 in the C++11 standard answers your question.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yep. :) I was only 12 seconds late!

Comment: @Columbo that's because I'm a Ninja

Comment: @DanielFrey vsoftco's book is correct, template functions are not implicitly inline. It's just that the language would not be very different if they were, as most of the rules regarding `inline` also apply to template functions. Also, the main rules are wrt the one definition rule, and ODR violations are not required to be diagnosed, so even if there are a few differences, non-inline and inline template functions could be treated the same by a particular implementation anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is always safe and covered by the ODR. §3.2/6:

> **There can be more than one definition of a […] non-static function template (14.5.6) […] in a program** provided that each definition appears in a different translation unit,
>   and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements. […long list…] **If the definitions of `D` satisfy all these requirements,
>   then the behavior is as if there were a single definition of `D`.** If the definitions of `D` do not satisfy these requirements, then the behavior is undefined.

The requirement list that I skipped should be satisfied if you write sane code.

Comment: Great! Do you know if this piece of standard is also in C++03/98?

Comment: @vsoftco Yep, §3.2/5.

Comment: Note that this does not necessarily mean that the duplicates are discarded by the linker as the OP posits -- an implementation with a weak linker might just make the functions local (static), keeping the duplication (wasting memory)

Comment: @ChrisDodd ok, but it won't spit an error (if the linker is stupid then it its problem :) )

Comment: @vsoftco Isn't a bad linker a problem for you?

Comment: @Columbo it is of course (in practice). I was however interested whether the behaviour is OK (no complains about duplicate symbols) according to a standard-compliant implementation.